# why does a simple cast from int to double not work

Tags: c++

i have a simple function, in which i need to divide two integers. But the casting does not work.
I can't understand what is wrong in my code:

```
   double new=0.0;
   if(N>0) new = double(Ns)/double(N);
```

The error-message at the place `double new;` is (error:expected unqualified-id) and at the place `new=double(Ns)/double(N)`
and at

Comment: Hint: a good clue that `new` is a reserved keyword, is the syntax highlighting. Notice how it's blue in your question, same as `for` and `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new` is a reserved keyword in C++. Pick another name for your variable:

```
   double double_new=0.0;
   if(N>0) double_new = double(Ns)/double(N);
```

Comment: oh sure!! Thank you a lot! How stupid to forget that!

Answer (score 2):

`new` is a reserved keyword in C++. You cannot have objects named `new`.